# Trouble accessing data in relationships in Ember

Tags: ember.js, model, attributes, ember-data

I'm having trouble saving data in this model relationship.  My models are as follows:

```
App.Flow = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  isCustom: DS.attr('boolean'),
  params: DS.hasMany('parameter', {async: true})
});

App.Parameter = DS.Model.extend({
  flow: DS.belongsTo('flow'),
  param: DS.attr('string'),
  param_tooltip: DS.attr('string'),
  param_value: DS.attr('string')
});
```

As you can see, I want Flows to have multiple Parameters.  I have a rudimentary setup using Flow and Parameter fixtures, which behave as expected in the templates.  However, when I try to create new ones in the controller, I have trouble setting the flow and parameter values correctly.

```
var p = this.store.createRecord('parameter', {
  param: "foo",
  param_tooltip: "world",
  param_value: "hello"
});

var f = this.store.createRecord('flow', {
  title: 'job',
  content: title,
  isCustom: true,
  params: [p] // doesn't seem to work
});

f.set('params', [p]); // doesn't seem to work
p.set('flow', f); // also doesn't seem to work

// Save the new model
p.save();
f.save();
```

I've tried a lot of solutions after staring at this and StackOverflow for a while (not just the ones listed).  I'm not really sure what to try next.  One thing that I noticed in the Ember inspector was that the ids of these created elements were not integers (they were something like the string 'fixture_0'), but I'm not really sure why that would be, whether its related, or how to fix it.

Thanks!

**Edit**

After dealing with promises ala kingpin's solution, the parameter seems like it is being set in the createFlow function I have when I check with print statements; however, I'm still having trouble accessing the parameters in both my template and in the removeFlow function.

```
createJob: function() {
  // ...
  f.get('params').then(function(params) {
    params.pushObject(p);
  });

  f.get('params').then(function(params) {
    console.log(params.toArray()[0].get('param')); // prints 'foo'
  });
  // ...
},

removeJob: function(flow) {
  console.log(flow.get('title')); // prints 'job'
  flow.get('params').then(function(params) {
    var arr = params.toArray();
    console.log(arr); // prints '[]'
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      console.log('hi'); // never gets printed
      arr[i].deleteRecord();
      arr[i].save();
    }
    flow.deleteRecord();
    flow.save();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` being async needs to be waited on before you can set a property or model on it (this is something that is being hardened out before 1.0 finally hits, but it's finicky right now in 1.0 beta).   The fixture_ids are applied if you're using the fixture adapter.

```
var store = this.store;
var p = store.createRecord('parameter', {
   param: "foo",
   param_tooltip: "world",
   param_value: "hello"
  });

 var f = this.store.createRecord('flow', {
   title: 'job',
   content: 'title',
   isCustom: true,
 });

f.get('params').then(function(params){
  params.pushObject(p);

});

 p.set('flow', f);
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/588/edit

Additionally saving using the fixture adapter seems to remove hasMany relationships when their is a manyToOne connection (aka both records have a relationship to each other, one of them being a hasMany).  Getting rid of one of the relationships fixes the issue (or using one of the real adapters)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/590/edit

Comment: Hm, it's still not quite working the way I'd expect.  I'm trying to access the parameters in a removeFlow function in the controller so I can delete the parameters before deleting the flow.  After fiddling around and converting the params MutableArray into a regular Javascript array, I was able to access individual parameters, at least in the createJob method.  However, it doesn't seem to work in the deleteJob method.  I'll update the main post.